# Can I use @ConditionalProperty with my custom annotation to avoid repeating configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I'd like to logically divide my Spring Boot App's code into several "features", using @OnConditional*family annotations.

I've found myself repeating a lot of code around, like:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty( prefix = "pib2.war.features.", value = "hello", matchIfMissing = false )
@RestController
public class HelloController {
...
}
```

In order to ease maintenance, I'd like to define meta-annotations, so that I can create some kind of "feature toggle", like:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@ConditionalOnProperty( prefix = "pib2.war.features" )
public @interface FeatureToggle {

    @AliasFor(annotation = ConditionalOnProperty.class )
    String[] value() default { };

    @AliasFor(annotation = ConditionalOnProperty.class )
    String[] name() default { };
}
```

So that my code becomes:

```
@FeatureToggle( "hello" )
@RestController
public class HelloController {
...
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working: the `OnPropertyCondition` evaluation code ignores by `@Aliased` fields and it just says that name is empty:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The name or value attribute of @ConditionalOnProperty must be specified
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition$Spec.getNames(OnPropertyCondition.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition$Spec.<init>(OnPropertyCondition.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.determineOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```

So I guess it's is not possible to create these shortcut meta-annotations? Am I wrong in my configuration? Should I write my own condition evaluator like 'OnPropertyCondition`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write your own conditions you should implement `org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition`

This is how `@Profile` work by defining a `ProfileCondition` class that implement `Condition` interface :

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Conditional(ProfileCondition.class)
public @interface Profile {

    /**
     * The set of profiles for which the annotated component should be registered.
     */
    String[] value();

}
```

Comment: I guess so: I implemented my own condition and it works. I had hoped for some annotation magic but sometimes to must do your coding. Thanks for feedback.